# How to structure a .Net projects? Common code, shared by different projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oop

I am using same constants in two different project in different visual studio solutions.

Project 1 is ASP.NET WEB API and 
Project 2 is client web application.

Constants example: 
1. BUYING_RATE 
2. THRESHOLD_LIMIT 
etc

My question is.

**Should I create a new library project just for handling constants and share this dll in both projects? I want to avoid
duplacate code in two different projects**

**Note 1:** I cannot add both projects (API project and client project) in one solution due to some limitations so ignore this 
 
**Note 2:** Both projects are managed by me

One more scenario is. ASP.NET WEB API will be consumed by 3rd parties as well. So should I provide the dll-s to them or API documentation is enough.

Or Am i thinking wrong about the design. If yes have a better solution, then what other options are to solve this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, create a shared  DLL.

Comment: You can try to use NuGet to share the assemblies.

Comment: It would be good to understand the limitations mentioned in Note 1. It's possible that you've misinterpreted some documentation or guidance that doesn't actually apply. Ruling out the 99% option requires careful consideration.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use a NuGet to share constants but I wouldn't. The main problem is that you will have to plan your constants beforehand or the NuGet publication will delay your progress.
2. When using a shared library, consider using variables instead of constants. It often happens that you need to change a constant value and you do not want to issue a full rebuild. Constant values are compiled into the assemblies referencing them. Variables get evaluated at run-time.
3. When making a shared library, consider providing a statically accessible instance container. It is often usable to provide different semi-constant value sets for different reader instances.

   ```
   //Constant-provider assembly code. Separate library that is.
   public class MyConstants
   {
       //Gets compiled into user code. Changing value -> rebuild all clients.
       //public const double BUYING_RATE = 0.5;

       //Gets evaluated in run-time. Changing value -> clients get new value.
       public readonly double BUYING_RATE = 0.5;

       private static MyConstants _default;
       static MyConstants()
       {
           _default = new MyConstants();
       }

       //Provide default instance. You can change it in run-time when needed.
       public static Default
       {
           get
           {
               return _default;
           }
       }
   }

   //Constant-user assembly code. Sample usage code for reader assemblier.
   private class User
   {
       public void Method1()
       {
           ... = MyConstants.Default.BUYING_RATE;
       }
   }
   ```